# https git clone url is not visible anymore

Tags: git, gerrit

I have upgraded gerrit from 2.11.7 to 2.14.1 , I can not understand why in UI, when i click on project, gerrit shows me its clone URL as only http but not https

```
git clone http://myuser@gerrit.mysite.com/git/a/project
```

It used to be https in earlier version , any idea what has changed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used "https" in the GERRIT_SITE/etc/gerrit.config options like in the example following?

```
[httpd]
    listenUrl = proxy-https://localhost:8080/

[gerrit]
    canonicalWebUrl = https://GERRIT-SERVER/
```

Comment: we are using nginx as reverse proxy and load balancer is taking care of https so we have set it to only proxy-http://127.0.0.1:8081/ and canonicalWebUrl = http://GERRIT-SERVER/